# How does #! work and how can I make it work for CoffeeScript?

Tags: macos, shell, coffeescript

Can I make a CoffeeScript file executable just like a Perl or shell script?

Something like adding

```
#!coffee
```

on top? (I tried that, and all I get is 'bad interpreter')

I'm on OS X if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee

console.log 'hello coffeescript!'
```

Just make sure you also make the file executable:

```
chmod +x myfile.coffee
```

Then you can run it with:

```
myfile.coffee
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the absolute path? "Bad interpreter" usually means there's a rogue newline at the end, e.g. you need to run `dos2unix` on it.

Comment: Can a rogue `\r` really throw it off?? I'm surprised on mac especially - `\r` used to be the mac line ending before OSX IIRC... 
I've not seen this before on other *nixes, but then I hardly use windows and thus very few dos line endings

Comment: Yes, it can. Happens to me all the time when I move from Cygwin (smart enough to handle it) to older `bash` shells. It's looking for (in my case) "`/usr/bin/perl\r`"

Comment: You're right, just tested this on my Ubuntu box... didn't like that `\r` if you've left trailing whitespace the error message becomes even more opaque - it tries to run a file called `\r` and just says "No such file or directory" with an apparently blank name...

Answer (score 1):

You need an absolute path (on linux at least, OSX may be different)

or you can cheat by using `env`

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
# **Your script here**
```

It looks like you've already made sure you've made the script executable if you are getting that error

Comment: For some reason, absolute path did not work, but `/usr/bin/env` does, thanks